# How to make git forget about a distant gitignore file?

Tags: windows, git, gitignore

Git is ignoring a directory that I want to track and index. I do not *ignore* this dir in any local gitignore file. When I inspect it, I get:

```
$git check-ignore -v my-ignored-dir
"I:\\path\\to\\external\\project\\.gitignore":33:my-ignored-dir/ my-ignored-dir
```

So the *ignore* instruction is coming from this external project file. The file belongs to the external project and I can't modify it. I can't find any reference to this project in my account (searching .bat files etc.).

How can I tell git to stop looking in this external file?

More generally, how does git know where to look for gitignore data and what determines the order of preference?

Comment: `git config --show-origin core.excludesFile`? See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-coreexcludesFile

Comment: You can add ignored paths with `git add -f -- <path>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses - these lead me to the solution:

```
$ git config --show-origin core.excludesFile
file:U://.gitconfig     I:\path\to\external\project/.gitignore
```

So this tells me that the *gitignore* file from the unwanted external project is defined in a file on my *U:* drive. I look in this file and find:

```
[core]
       excludesfile = I:\\path\\to\\external\\project\\.gitignore
```

Aha! - I worked on this project a couple of years ago. I must've ran some setup script that inserted this line into my personal *.gitconfig*. I zap the line and all is well...